# JavaScrip toLocaleDateString() prints wrong date

Tags: javascript, angular, date, time, timestamp

i want to print this date: **21.10.2022**

with following timestamp: **1666344563**

*my code:*

```
new Date(parseInt(element.createdAt)).toLocaleDateString())
```

FYI element.createdAt = '1666344563'

it prints in chrome: 20.01.1970

can someone explain whats happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript uses miliseconds timestamps. Your value is made from seconds. To make it work just multiply this value by 1000 like so:

```
new Date(parseInt(element.createdAt) * 1000).toLocaleDateString())
```

@EDIT:
Thanks @NineBerry for noticing. Multiply after parsing.

Comment: No need to call `parseInt` when you multiply -- it happens implicitly.